# Can't typecast to int in C; Error: Expected expression before int

Tags: c, casting, integer, binary-search

```
int arr5[8]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80};
len=8;
int beg=0,mid,end=len-1,loc;
mid=int((beg+end)/2);
printf("%d",mid);
```

I was trying to write a code for binary search but can't typecast the value of (beg+end)/2 to mid.

```
 error: expected expression before 'int'
         mid=int((beg+end)/2);
             ^~~
```

Comment: You go thte syntax wrong. How wrong is hard to tell without a [mre]. But what makes you even try to typecast the result of an int operation to int?  Did you try just assigning? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: `mid = (int)((beg + end) / 2);` But the cast isn't needed since you are doing integer division.

Comment: I am convinced that at the root of your problem (syntax is only a side issue...) your misunderstanding is about how integer division work in C; and that if you do not clear that misunderstanding you will have more, and more difficult problems. Telling you the syntax of what you unnecesarily try will not solve your deeper problem. What you need to understand is explained in the answers to the question I will link. And the existing answer here provides the syntax, if you are not convinced of what I am trying to tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters using the type specifier `int` in this statement

```
mid=int((beg+end)/2);
```

does not make a sense.

It is enough to write

```
mid=(beg+end)/2;
```

As all operands in the expression in the right side of the assignment have the type `int` then the evaluated value also has the type `int`.

As for the casting then in C you have to write

```
mid= ( int )((beg+end)/2);
```